# Can I view my Xbox 360 Screen on my Mac by using an HDMI to minidisplay port adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, data-transfer, hdmi

Or can I not have input into the Macbook?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the minidisplay port for input. Your best chance to get video input on your Mac is by using a video capture device (from [Elgato](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/int/mainmenu/products/Video-Capture/product1.en.html) for example).